# Модераторы отклоняют тревоги бессмысленными и лживыми отписками

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, удаление-ответов, модераторский-произвол

Когда половина сообщества опять не справилась с самостоятельной модерацией и сочла пост из шести непонятных слов полноценным ответом, я был вынужден начать тыкать тревогу «требуется вмешательство модератора» с пояснением «не является ответом».

В ответ логично ожидать или принятие тревоги, или отклонение с причиной вроде «это на самом деле ответ» или «модератор не понял, почему это не является ответом» или что-нибудь в таком духе.

Однако на практике вместо этих двух вариантов я на каждую тревогу получаю стандартную отписку:

> не следует использовать сигнал тревоги, чтобы указать на неточность или неверность ответа

Это же абсурд! Я и так не использовал сигнал тревоги, чтобы указать на неточность или неверность ответа — это же и так не ответ. Это не неточный ответ, это не неверный ответ — это просто **не ответ**. Отклонение тревоги про не-ответ с отпиской про ответ противоречит здравому смыслу. Это означает одно из двух: или модераторы просто поленились вникнуть в суть тревоги и ткнули стандартную отписку не глядя, или же тревоги отклоняются с этой причиной осознанно и такой причиной мне, фактически, приписывают то, чего я не делал и не пытался делать — ну то есть это просто **ложь**.

Говоря кратко: **причина отклонения тревоги не соответствует самой тревоге.**

Примерно это я и высказал в очередной тревоге и получил в ответ... ту же самую бессмысленную отписку!

У нас тут роботы вместо модераторов сидят, что ли?

Модераторы, если вам лень разбираться в конкретной тревоге — ну оставьте её висеть нерешённой, кто-нибудь другой рассмотрит. Если вам лень вникать и писать адекватный ответ в стиле «Это является ответом, потому что [причина 1] и [причина 2], посему тревога отклоняется» — ну просто не трогайте ничего. Если вам совсем лень выполнять функции модератора — ну никто не заставляет, покиньте пост, вон Barmaley уже один раз уходил в добровольную отставку, и ничего.

А вот отклонять тревоги с бессмысленной отпиской в лучших традициях российской бюрократии — это точно не то, что стоит делать.

Даже если я не прав и моя тревога должна быть отклонена — это не позволяет писать всякий абсурд в причине отклонения.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117526/discussion-on-question-by-andreymal----).

Answer (score 9):

Насколько я понимаю, суть отклонения тревоги для "неправильного ответа" в следующем: модератор не обязан, да и не может быть экспертом по всем возможным технологиям, обсуждаемым на сайте. Т.о. под пункт "не является" ответом стоит флагать только **явные** не ответы, например, какой-то другой вопрос, или совет обратиться на другой сайт, или даже спам (хотя для этого есть отдельная тревога). Но если в сообщении содержится описание как (по задумке автора ответа) сделать то, что требуется в вопросе, и оказывается, что подход в сообщении по сути не работает, то такое сообщение не подходит под тревогу "не является ответом". Такое сообщение является ошибочным ответом. И это ошибочное состояние следует отразить минусами, а не тревогой, вот и всё.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117527/discussion-on-answer-by-------).

Answer (score 7):

Среднее яблоко - это тоже ответ, даже если он и упускает кучу накладываемых ограничений.

[image]

Comment: Только вот на самом деле речь идёт о предпоследнем яблоке.

Comment: @andreymal, нет, потому что github pages - это не место, где надо узнать ответ, а способ развернуть статический сайт на хостинге.

Comment: В этом не-ответе не описано никакого способа развернуть статический сайт на хостинге, а просто дано какое-то название. Это не ответ. И это даже хуже чем ответ-ссылка.

Comment: И уже +4. Потому что прав как всегда ;)

Comment: И кстати, этот ваш «ответ» — тоже не ответ, потому что вы уводите тему в оффтопик. Сейчас тревогу поставлю.

Comment: Из-за вашего оффтопика пришлось откатить текст вопроса к предыдущей версии.

Comment: Почему без ссылки на [авторский пост](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/339911) с картинкой? Негоже для модератора плагиатом заниматься.

Comment: Раз уж подняли мой старый вопрос, то закину и сюда тоже https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXiUD.jpg